# CSS selector for the next same parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

I'm restyling a legacy app, changing only the .css behind it.
In a simplified scenario I have something like this:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.name {
  background-color: red;
}

div+td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='name'>Sean</div>
    </td>
    <td>Connery</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='name'>Pierce</div>
    </td>
    <td>Brosnan</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to find a way (with pure css) to set background color for *td* elements immediately after the *td* that contain the div with class='name'. In other words I'd like to set background color for cells with 'Connery' and 'Brosnan'.

In my example I've used the selector *div + td* which is obviously wrong.

Here the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg2uvh3c/).

Comment: This can be done using js only.

Comment: In simple words you can't do this using CSS, for detailed you can [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: If you want it in css, then your have to give a class for the parent of .name class.

Comment: Or move the class to the `td` instead of the `div`, in which case you can say `td.name + td`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "next same parent" selector in CSS. You can use the `:nth-child` selector to always select the second td:

```
td:nth-child(2) {...}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div.name {
  background-color: red;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='name'>Sean</div>
    </td>
    <td>Connery</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='name'>Pierce</div>
    </td>
    <td>Brosnan</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or (as suggested in the comments), move your `class="name"` to the td element and use the adjacent sibling selector `+`:

```
.name + td {...}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.name {
  background-color: red;
}

.name + td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='name'>
      <div>Sean</div>
    </td>
    <td>Connery</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='name'>
      <div>Pierce</div>
    </td>
    <td>Brosnan</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```